# Create table in Crystal Reports like SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, crystal-reports, ssrs-2008-r2, ifs-erp

Is there a way to auto create a table object in crystal reports (2011) with grid lines, where you can drag the fields in and it will auto create the headers, and allow vertical and horizontal resizing, like you can do in SSRS. Drawing the lines or boxes and then aligning and resizing the detail and headers manually, snapping to the grid, matching stuff to the page markers, etc., is very cumbersome and a complete waste of time. I would use SSRS, but I am creating forms that integrate into a particular ERP system and you can only use Crystal unfortunately.

If this is not possible, what is the fastest and most efficient way to get this done.

This is probably a long shot, but IFS is the ERP if anyone knows it, and if there is a way to create forms in IFS 8.1 with SSRS instead. I believe you can do it in version 9, but seems that it is not possible in version 8.1.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Unfortunately **Crystal Reports** doesn't have any utility to create a table Grid.

But you can do **two things** in this situation.

---

Fisrt One:

- Lets assume you have a simple report having header, details and footer. **Insert Box** from tool bar and start **drawing** from **header** to **footer** including detail section. This will create outside **border** of **table**.
- To **draw column** lines just **insert line** and **link** it with top and bottom of outside **border**
- **Reduce grid size**(File->Options->Layout) or **disable Snap To Grid** or use **ALT key** for **smooth re-sizing and movement** of objects

---

Second one:

- **Insert** a **Cross-Tab** in report footer.
- Go to **Cross-Tab Expert**, Add your **desired Fields** in Rows.
- Go to **Customize Style**, **Select Each row** and in **Group Options** check suppress subtotals
- Go to **Format Grid** Lines and **unmark draw** for all lines for **columns.**

I will **suggest** you to use **first one** if you are not much familiar to **Cross-Tab**, Cross-Tab generates lines automatically but it has **some issues** like **excel export**, **Sorting**,**Not Having Can grow**. and it takes **more time** then conventional solution while solving these issues.

Comment: Thanks, yes the first one helps speed up the process. Still painful, but less so now ;-)